# How do I derive that the function g(n) below has a time complexity of O(n)?

Tags: python-3.x, function, loops, time-complexity

```
def g(n):
    s = 0 
    for i in range(n):

        # min(a,b) returns the smaller value of a and b 
        for j in range(min(100,i)): 
            s = s + 1
    return s
```

As stated in the title,  "How do I derive that the time complexity of function g(n) is O(n)?"

Like it seems to me that the double for loop will let the time complexity be closer to O(n<sup>2</sup>) instead of O(n)?

To be more specific, this was my thought process (with reference to the inner for-loop):

```
for j in range(min(100,i)):
```

- For large values of n (n >> 100), it seems to me that its reasonable to state that the time complexity is O(n)
- While for values of n (n < 100), it seems to me that O(n<sup>2</sup>) time complexity will make more sense

Is this line of reasoning correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner loop is bounded by a constant so the running time of the whole thing is O(n).

Briefly the definition of the Big-O is that for large `n`'s some function `f(n)` is `O(g(n))` if there exists a constant `k` such that `f(n) ≤ k * g(n)`. In this case since the inner loop will run *at most* 100 times the time the program takes to run grows with `n` as something like `f(n) = 100*n + m` where `m` is some constant. Thus we can see that the running time of this program is `O(n)` because `100*n + m` grows like just `100*n` if `n` is large relative to `m` and `100*n` will always be less than `k*n` if `k` is some constant greater than 100.